# Is there a css selector like :scrollbar-shown?

Tags: css

I have a div with `overflow-x:auto` and I need to show a different styling if append dynamic content inside of it that makes the scrollbar appear.

**Which is the simplest way to show a different style to an auto overflowing div while it is scrollable?**

EDIT: for info, I want to make a ::after element appear

Comment: what kind of style you want to apply?

Comment: I won't post it as an answer because I'm not sure it's what you are looking for. But in css you also could play with something like this `a:not([data-scroll='0'])`. In this way you would apply your css when the scroll is over 0. I'm not confident with this type of css so it's better for you to find more about it on internet/so. Let me know if this help you!

Comment: if you share more context , we can found a workaround for your case. You accepted the duplicate that simply no but it can be a yes for you